# ODBC connection working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, odbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL server 2008 with ODBC_CONNECT(), somehow I managed to work it on localhost, but when I tried to upload it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

here is my code with connection string

```
$server = '***.***.***.**';
$user = '******';
$pass = '*********';
$port = '*******';
$database = '********';

//connection string
$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database";
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);

if ($conn) {
    echo "connected";

}
else {
     echo "not connected";
}
```

I have googled it, and I came to know that it may be due to ODBC driver missing issue, I am running PHP7 on my localhost which supports ODBC drivers by default but on server (hosting company) where I am trying to upload it has PHP5, which need to install odbc driver, I have talked with my hosting providers and they say that they cant do anything on it.

Is there any solution for this issue? What can I do to make it work right? Or in any way I don't have anything in my hands to make right?

Comment: Is this shared hosting? If so, you'll need to move hosts. If it's a VPS or dedicated server, you'll have to install the ODBC extension yourself.

Comment: it is a shared hosting

Comment: strange thing is previous developer's code works fine, he uses .net and I used PHP

Comment: That's not shocking, as .NET is a Microsoft product and would for obvious reasons include Microsoft SQL support by default. PHP is not a Microsoft product, so MSSQL support is optional.

Comment: so, changing hosting is the only solution left ?

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, yes, as your host has refused to assist. If you're on VPS/dedicated you can do whatever you want with the server.

Comment: install first pear the odbc extension!